# Send mass emails from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

We have a fairly large application and part of that application requires the sending of around 300k emails a day.

Doing this in .net is insanely slow, to fix this we did it uses threads which has the effect of making the entire server come to a grind.

Im sure there are bigger apps out there sending more emails.

What is the best way to send a large volume of emails in a reasonable time frame.

Here is the code

Part 1 thread the send

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    Utility.sendTemplatedEmail(model.email, "noreply@fakedomain.com", "New Jobs!", fullHtml: fullHtml, checkUnsubscribed: false, smtpClient: smtp);
    smtp.Dispose();

    lock (syncObject) 
    {
        emailCounter++;
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("sent and smtp client closed: {0} -- email number: {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), emailCounter.ToString()));

        writer.Flush();
        if (emailCounter == numberOfGroupedMatches) 
        {
            writer.Close();
            System.IO.File.Move(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + "emailLog.txt", Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + "emailLog-Finished.txt");
        }
    }
});
```

Part 2 actual send

```
fullHtml = (fullHtml == null ? ViewToString("~/View/Shared/_DocumentTemplate.cshtml", controllerContext, new emailModel { body = body, subject = subject }) : fullHtml);
messageMail.Body = fullHtml;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = (smtpClient == null ? new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient() : smtpClient);
smtp.Send(messageMail);
```

Comment: Please narrow your question. This is much too broad. Throwing threads at it will block threads waiting for an IO operation. Throwing more threads than CPUs at it will cause Windows to context switch constantly - hence your issues. Perhaps you could show us your code and we could help identify what your issue is.

Comment: Also - you might need to consider more than one server if you want nicer performance. Just throwing that out there.

Comment: you can use the `SendMailAsync` for non-blocking sending but I'm not sure if I am helping enabling yet another spam bot here ...

Comment: Its very simple, loop over a query and generate and send emails. Without threads it takes more than a day to send. That isn't acceptable either.

Comment: Its not a spam bot, its a legimate website where people subscribe to job notifications.

Comment: Dale, please add your code so we see what you're trying to do

Comment: If it really takes a day you on one cpu/thread and you have 8 cpus in your server it will still take more than 4 hours, no matter what...

Comment: have you profiled this to see where you *waste* the time?

Comment: I pasted the code. @CarstenKönig thats not right, threading it makes a huge difference but from 30+ hours to 1 hour.

Comment: but just because you are waiting on IO ... just use async

Comment: BTW: the way you dispose your SmtpClient looks strange

Comment: So much blocking IO ... and you've also got some synchronization there too ...

Comment: I used to save a Message record to Database table, and save recipients emails to another table with Link to message record, then  I have 2-3 desktop Apps running on different servers that takes recipients emails to send them the message.

Comment: `Task.Run(() => lock(_object) {...})` enough said.

Comment: @DaleFraser Which .NET framework are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 mvc 5

Comment: You DO realise your code is single threaded, right? That is you have lots of threads but only one that ever does any work.

Comment: I dont believe that to be correct as I said it went from 30+ hours to 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threads to do async IO is unnecessary (most of time) and will cause your program to not really scale out well, as you're probably noticing right now.

First, im not sure why you're using threads if you eventually have to `lock` on a mutual object, that is usually a sign of a code smell, i suggest you think about that again.

A good idea would be to use [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) with a combination of [`async-await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature of C#5:

```
public async Task SendSmtpMailAsync()
{
    fullHtml = (fullHtml == null ? ViewToString("~/View/Shared/_DocumentTemplate.cshtml", controllerContext, new emailModel { body = body, subject = subject }) : fullHtml);
    messageMail.Body = fullHtml;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = smtpClient ?? new SmtpClient();
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(messageMail);
}
```

You can use it inside the first piece of code like this:

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
{
    await Utility.SendTemplatedMailAsync(model.email, "noreply@fakedomain.com", "New Jobs!", fullHtml: fullHtml, checkUnsubscribed: false, smtpClient: smtp);
}

// Note i removed the lock from this piece of code. If you have to execute multiple async methods concurrently (using Task.WhenAll), then maybe it should be re-added 
emailCounter++;
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("sent and smtp client closed: {0} -- email number: {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), emailCounter.ToString()));

writer.Flush();
if (emailCounter == numberOfGroupedMatches) 
{
    writer.Close();
    System.IO.File.Move(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + "emailLog.txt", Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + "emailLog-Finished.txt");
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the most sensible answer to date

Comment: Note the null coalescing operator `??` i used instead of `== null`, its much less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the built in .Net System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient library, I suggest that you look into making your own or using another third party library. I also deal with large volume of email generated from a .Net Windows Service... and my mileage increased dramatically when I stopped letting Microsoft send my mail for me.

1. The LumiSoft.Net.SMTP.Client is a reliable library, and performs well
2. The following class is one I use as a "first choice", it is very lightweight... but may or may not work with the mail server you are sending to. In my case I pass all my SMTP traffic to SendGrid, so it saves me a lot of CPU cycles. Original author here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9637/SMTP-MailMessage-done-right

   using System;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.Sockets;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   using System.Net.Mail;

   namespace General.Utilities.Mail
   {
       public class SMTPSendRawMIME
       {
       #region Constructor
       public SMTPSendRawMIME()
       {

   ```
   }
   #endregion

   //The following methods are KNOWN to be flawed... they work only with some SMTP Servers... not many.... 
   //On the other hand, they run very fast... so they are worth using when possible like with SendGrid
   #region Send Raw Mime

   #region Static Send Methods
   public static void SendEmail(SmtpClient Server, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage) //bool SSL, 
   {
       SMTPSendRawMIME objMailClient = new SMTPSendRawMIME();
       objMailClient.Send(Server, FromEmail, ToEmail, MIMEMessage);
   }

   public static void SendEmail(General.Utilities.Mail.MailTools.MailServerTypes enuUseServerType, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage) //bool SSL, 
   {
       SmtpClient objServer = General.Utilities.Mail.MailTools.GetMailServer(enuUseServerType);
       SMTPSendRawMIME objMailClient = new SMTPSendRawMIME();
       objMailClient.Send(objServer, FromEmail, ToEmail, MIMEMessage);
   }
   #endregion

   public void Send(SmtpClient Server, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage) //bool SSL, 
   {
       if (Server.Credentials != null)
       {
           //if (SSL)
               //SendSSL(Server.Host, Server.Port, ((NetworkCredential)Server.Credentials).UserName, ((NetworkCredential)Server.Credentials).Password, FromEmail, ToEmail, MIMEMessage);
           //else
               Send(Server.Host, Server.Port, ((NetworkCredential)Server.Credentials).UserName, ((NetworkCredential)Server.Credentials).Password, FromEmail, ToEmail, MIMEMessage);
       }
       else
       {
           SendToOpenRelay(Server.Host, Server.Port, FromEmail, ToEmail, MIMEMessage);
       }

   }

   #region BASE Send
   /// <summary>
   /// Sends the message via a socket connection to an SMTP relay host. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="hostname">Friendly-name or IP address of SMTP relay host</param>
   /// <param name="port">Port on which to connect to SMTP relay host</param>
   /// <param name="username"></param>
   /// <param name="password"></param>
   public void Send(string HostName, int Port, string UserName, string Password, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage)
   {
       const int bufsize = 1000;
       TcpClient smtp;
       NetworkStream ns;
       int cb, startOfBlock;
       byte[] recv = new byte[bufsize];
       byte[] data;
       string message, block;

       try
       {

           smtp = new TcpClient(HostName, Port);
           ns = smtp.GetStream();
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           message = "EHLO\r\n";
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to establish SMTP session with {0}:{1}", HostName, Port), ex);
       }

       try
       {

           //figure out the line containing 250-AUTH
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           startOfBlock = message.IndexOf("250-AUTH");
           block = message.Substring(startOfBlock, message.IndexOf("\n", startOfBlock) - startOfBlock);
           //check the auth protocols
           if (-1 == block.IndexOf("LOGIN"))
               throw new Exception("Mailhost does not support LOGIN authentication");

           message = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("334"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to AUTH LOGIN:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("{0}\r\n", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UserName)));
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client (username)");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("334"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to username:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("{0}\r\n", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password)));
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client (password)");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (message.StartsWith("535"))
               throw new Exception("Authentication unsuccessful");
           if (!message.StartsWith("2"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to password:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("MAIL FROM: <{0}>\r\n", FromEmail);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to MAIL FROM:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("RCPT TO: <{0}>\r\n", ToEmail);
           string strRcptToMessage = message;
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to RCPT TO:\n{0}", message + " (" + strRcptToMessage + ")"));

           message = "DATA\r\n";
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("354"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to DATA:\n{0}", message));

           //message = payload + "\r\n.\r\n";
           //data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MIMEMessage) + "\r\n.\r\n");
           data = MIMEMessage;
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

           message = "\r\n.\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to end of data marker (\\r\\n.\\r\\n):\n{0}", message));

           message = "QUIT\r\n";
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           General.Utilities.Debugging.Report.SendError("SMTP Communication Error", ex);
           throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP Communication Error: {0}", message), ex);
       }
       finally
       {
           if (null != smtp) smtp.Close();
       }
   }
   #endregion

   #region BASE SendSSL
   /// <summary>
   /// Sends the message via a socket connection to an SMTP relay host. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="hostname">Friendly-name or IP address of SMTP relay host</param>
   /// <param name="port">Port on which to connect to SMTP relay host</param>
   /// <param name="username"></param>
   /// <param name="password"></param>
   private void SendSSL(string HostName, int Port, string UserName, string Password, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage)
   {
       //This Doesn't Work Yet... :(

       const int bufsize = 1000;
       TcpClient smtp;
       System.Net.Security.SslStream ns;
       int cb, startOfBlock;
       byte[] recv = new byte[bufsize];
       byte[] data;
       string message, block;

       try
       {

           smtp = new TcpClient(HostName, Port);
           ns = new System.Net.Security.SslStream(smtp.GetStream(), true);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           message = "EHLO\r\n";
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to establish SMTP session with {0}:{1}", HostName, Port), ex);
       }

       try
       {

           //figure out the line containing 250-AUTH
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           startOfBlock = message.IndexOf("250-AUTH");
           block = message.Substring(startOfBlock, message.IndexOf("\n", startOfBlock) - startOfBlock);
           //check the auth protocols
           if (-1 == block.IndexOf("LOGIN"))
               throw new Exception("Mailhost does not support LOGIN authentication");

           message = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("334"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to AUTH LOGIN:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("{0}\r\n", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UserName)));
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client (username)");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("334"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to username:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("{0}\r\n", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password)));
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client (password)");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (message.StartsWith("535"))
               throw new Exception("Authentication unsuccessful");
           if (!message.StartsWith("2"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to password:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("MAIL FROM: <{0}>\r\n", FromEmail);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to MAIL FROM:\n{0}", message));

           message = string.Format("RCPT TO: <{0}>\r\n", ToEmail);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to RCPT TO:\n{0}", message));

           message = "DATA\r\n";
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("354"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to DATA:\n{0}", message));

           data = MIMEMessage;
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           message = "\r\n.\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

           clearBuf(recv);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Server");
           if (!message.StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected reply to end of data marker (\\r\\n.\\r\\n):\n{0}", message));

           message = "QUIT\r\n";
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message, "Client");
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP Communication Error: {0}", message), ex);
       }
       finally
       {
           if (null != smtp) smtp.Close();
       }
   }
   #endregion

   #region BASE SendToOpenRelay
   /// <summary>
   /// Sends the message via a socket connection to an SMTP relay host. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="hostname">Friendly-name or IP address of SMTP relay host</param>
   /// <param name="port">Port on which to connect to SMTP relay host</param>
   public void SendToOpenRelay(string HostName, int Port, string FromEmail, string ToEmail, byte[] MIMEMessage)
   {

       TcpClient smtp;
       NetworkStream ns;
       int cb;
       byte[] recv = new byte[256];
       byte[] data;
       string message;

       try
       {
           smtp = new TcpClient(HostName, Port);
           ns = smtp.GetStream();
           message = "HELO\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv), "Server");
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to establish SMTP session with {0}:{1}", HostName, Port), ex);
       }

       try
       {
           message = string.Format("MAIL FROM: <{0}>\r\n", FromEmail);
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           if (!Convert.ToString(recv).StartsWith("501"))
               throw new Exception("Malformed sender address");
           if (!Convert.ToString(recv).StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP host responded incorrectly to MAIL FROM:, response was:\n{0}", Convert.ToString(recv)));
           message = string.Format("RCPT TO: <{0}>\r\n", ToEmail);
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           if (Convert.ToString(recv).StartsWith("501"))
               throw new Exception("Malformed recipient address");
           if (!Convert.ToString(recv).StartsWith("250"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP host responded incorrectly to RCPT TO:, response was:\n{0}", Convert.ToString(recv)));
           message = "DATA\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           if (!Convert.ToString(recv).StartsWith("354"))
               throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP host responded incorrectly to DATA, response was:\n{0}", Convert.ToString(recv)));
           data = MIMEMessage;
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           message = "\r\n.\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
           cb = ns.Read(recv, 0, recv.Length);
           message = "QUIT\r\n";
           data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
           ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {



               throw new Exception(string.Format("SMTP Communication Error: {0}", message), ex);
           }
           finally
           {
               if (null != smtp) smtp.Close();
           }
       }
       #endregion

       #region clearBuf
       private void clearBuf(byte[] buf)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++) buf[i] = 0;
       }
       #endregion

       #endregion

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: We also use sendgrid. You say make it more reliable, is it not reliable?

Comment: It is reliable for SendGrid's SMTP API, I've just noticed that the class does not support all SMTP servers (for reasons I don't currently understand). Since it does support SendGrid's servers, and it is the most efficient method I have found, I wrote my code logic to use this class first... then use LumiSoft library in the case of a failure. In practice... the LumiSoft library is not being used... but it's there just in case.

Comment: Please note, if you go down this road you will be taking a crash course in MIME protocol's finer points. The .Net library does a lot of automatic work for you that my code sample does not. The SMTPSendRawMIME class expects a fully valid MIME message, with all the headers already set. I had to create my own methods of Reading/Writing mime messages in order to do this, borrowing code where I could find it... making it from scratch quite frequently. The end result is a very robust mail server... but it's not a quick fix.

Comment: Also, there is a bug in the SendGrid system that can cause messages with more than 2,000 RCPT-TO's to never be delivered... even though you will get a 250 "success" response from their server. My code always breaks up the messages into batches of 500 recipients before I pass it on to SendGrid via the SMTP API.

Comment: Every email is specific to a user thus 1 email 1 person